# How can I revert a user in Google Cloud Identity back to an ordinary account?

Tags: google-workspace, google-cloud-identity

I'm using Google Cloud Identity Free Edition and controlling users in Cloud Identity now.
Before the users are controlled in Cloud Identity, they were ordinary accounts in Google.
Are there any methods to revert them back to ordinary users in Google without deleting their accounts in Cloud Identity?
I want to return them to as they were private accounts in Google.

Answer (score 0):

A Google Cloud Identity user is a G Suite account without a license. That means, the Google Cloud Identity email does not have a G Suite license assigned so you just need to assign a G Suite license to that specific Cloud Identity Account.

Make sure that your domain have G Suite licenses available. Here is a Help Center Article with more information about how to manage the G Suite licenses https://support.google.com/a/answer/1727173?hl=en I hope that helps.